# Is Observable doOnNext thread-safet when merge Observables to one Observable

Tags: thread-safety, observable, rx-java2

I have a list of Observables, each Observable was subscribeOn a pooled thread Scheduler, I merged list of Observable to one Observable by 
Observable.merge(observables). Is the merge result observable doOnNext method is thread-safet? The code sample is below.

```
    ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
            .setDaemon(true)
            .setNameFormat("pooled-%s")
            .build();
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(threadFactory);
    List<Observable<String>> observableList = Stream.of("1", "2", "3", "4")
            .map(o -> {
                        Observable<String> ob = Observable.create(
                                emitter -> {
                                    Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(50));
                                    System.out.println("emitter:" + o + " Thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                                    emitter.onNext(o);
                                    emitter.onComplete();
                                });
                        return ob.subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executorService));
                    }
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(); //is need thread safe list here ?

    Observable.merge(observableList)
            .doOnNext(e -> {
                Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(50));
                System.out.println("doOnNext:" + e + " Thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                result.add(e);
            })
            .blockingLast();
```

case 1:
When I run the output seems that the doOnNext called by a signle thread.

```
    emitter:2 Thread:pooled-1
    emitter:3 Thread:pooled-2
    emitter:4 Thread:pooled-3
    emitter:1 Thread:pooled-0
    doOnNext:2 Thread:pooled-1
    doOnNext:1 Thread:pooled-1
    doOnNext:3 Thread:pooled-1
    doOnNext:4 Thread:pooled-1
```

case 2:
When i debug step by step the output changed and seem the doOnNext called by mulit thread.

```
    emitter:1 Thread:pooled-0
    doOnNext:1 Thread:pooled-0
    emitter:4 Thread:pooled-3
    emitter:3 Thread:pooled-2
    emitter:2 Thread:pooled-1
    doOnNext:4 Thread:pooled-3
    doOnNext:2 Thread:pooled-3
    doOnNext:3 Thread:pooled-3
```

I was confused.

1. I didn't see any code to switch threads between emitter and doOnNext, so why "case 1" occur if I miss same code.
2. Is doOnNext is not tread-safe in this case and result list should use thread -safe list.
3. The Observable.toList method internal use ArrayList is that has concurrency problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Flows are sequential and guaranteed to be non-overlapping in operators, especially in combining/coordinating ones. However, this doesn't rule out a `doOnNext` "jumping" between threads. If you want to ensure `doOnNext` runs on the same thread always, use `observeOn` before it.

> I didn't see any code to switch threads between emitter and doOnNext, so why "case 1" occur if I miss same code.

Flows can drive `merge` from any number of threads and push through it.

> Is doOnNext is not tread-safe in this case and result list should use thread -safe list.

`doOnNext` is thread safe regarding its input parameter and execution. If your callback is stateful or captures global state, multiple flow realizations can conflict. Those have to be synchronized via external means.

> The Observable.toList method internal use ArrayList is that has concurrency problem in this case.

`toList` is guaranteed to be driven non-overlappingly and its internal `ArrayList` is per subscriber thus there is no concurrency issue there.

Comment: `toList is guaranteed to be driven non-overlappingly` but `toList` internal ArrayList is may access add element  by muilt thread. Is that has  **Visibility**  and **Atomicity**  problem. non-overlappingly only relate to **Ordering**.  [Atomicity Visibility Ordering](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpj/jmm.html).  If there is something wrong with my understanding?

Comment: RxJava internals are usually not an user concern and the implementation has the proper JMM semantics by default.

Comment: With you reply and explore the Rxjava api, I found there is a `toList` method with  `collectionSupplier`. I got what you mean of **user concern** and what the Rxjava framework do. an user should consider to use appropriate api in different situations. Rxjava framework provider the api for different situations. Thank you  @akarnokd.